# Why I need to refresh page to get realtime data in Google Analytics?

Tags: c#, google-analytics, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to implement google analytics in my mvc5 .Net website.
I have created a partial view and paste my googletagmanager script inside, and I have rendered my GoogleAnalytics partial view in my main layout.
The problem is that if I browse through the website, I didn't received Google Analytics in realtime. I have to press F5 (in my website) to refresh the page everytime in order to see which page is visited in realtime.
Is anyone has any solution to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: You mean F5 on the GA website?

Comment: Sorry, no in my website

Comment: Something has to request the update or there has to be a mechanism for the server to push an update.  For client-side approach, take a look at AJAX.  For server-side, take a look at SignalR.